# find the largest count of ingredients

Tags: pandas, dataframe, graph, networkx

I have two df. In the first df, all the recipes, in the second, the ingredients of the recipes

Recipes

```
       RecipeId     Name
0      789         Pizza
1      790         Soup
2      791         Sushi
3      792         Cake
4      793        Sandwich
5      794         Bread
6      795        Sausage
```

Ingredients

```
     id  RecipeId         Name
0     1       789        Flour
1     2       789        Water
2   795       789      Sausage
3     3       789       Olives
4     4       789         Salt
5   794       793        Bread
6   795       793      Sausage
7     1       794        Flour
8     2       794        Water
9     4       794         Salt
10    5       795  Ground meat
11    4       795         Salt
```

1.How can I find the recipe with the most ingredients, including all ingredients, such as a sandwich, which has bread (flour, water, salt) and sausages (ground meat and salt) = 5 ingredients?
2.How can I find the recipe with the most nested recipes (not single ingredients)
3.And the ingredient most often used in recipes?

Comment: flour/water/salt and groundmeat/salt is only 4 ingredients. salt is duplicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot solve this easily with pandas only. This is a graph problem.

Here is your (directed) graph:

[image: graph]

You can use `network` to build the graph from your DataFrame, the count the number of terminal descendants per node:

```
import networkx as nx

df = (recipes.merge(ingredients, on='RecipeId',
                    suffixes=('_recipe', '_ingredient'))
      )


G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Name_recipe', target='Name_ingredient',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

counts = {n: sum(1 for x in nx.descendants(G, n) if G.out_degree(x)==0)
          for n in G.nodes}
```

output:

```
{'Pizza': 5,
 'Flour': 0,
 'Water': 0,
 'Sausage': 2,
 'Olives': 0,
 'Salt': 0,
 'Sandwich': 4,
 'Bread': 3,
 'Ground meat': 0}
```

##### left merge

If you want to count soup/sushi/cake you can use a left merge and skip the NaN:

[image]

```
import networkx as nx

df = (recipes.merge(ingredients, on='RecipeId',
                    suffixes=('_recipe', '_ingredient'),
                    how='left')
             .fillna('drop')
      )

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Name_recipe', target='Name_ingredient',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

G.remove_node('drop')

out = {n: sum(1 for x in nx.descendants(G, n) if G.out_degree(x)==0)
       for n in G.nodes}
```

output:

```
{'Pizza': 5,
 'Flour': 0,
 'Water': 0,
 'Sausage': 2,
 'Olives': 0,
 'Salt': 0,
 'Soup': 0,
 'Sushi': 0,
 'Cake': 0,
 'Sandwich': 4,
 'Bread': 3,
 'Ground meat': 0}
```

##### output as pandas Series

```
pd.Series(out).reindex(recipes['Name'])
```

output:

```
Name
Pizza       5
Soup        0
Sushi       0
Cake        0
Sandwich    4
Bread       3
Sausage     2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hey, your `sandwich` value is showing 4. It should be 2 right ??

Comment: @Sanju, no because the ingredients are recursive. Quoting OP: "*sandwich, which has bread (flour, water, salt) and sausages (ground meat and salt) = 5 ingredients*", which I would say should reduce to 4 as salt is counted twice.

Comment: @Sanju however if you wanted to have 2, you could only count the **direct** descendants ;)

Comment: Yes you are right. Now I saw it on the `id` column.

Comment: @mozway Thank you very much, it was very interesting to learn about graphs.
Can you help with two more questions to finally understand how the networkx package works?
How can I find the recipe with the most nested recipes (not single ingredients) and the ingredient most often used in recipes?